# PHP / jQuery Upload

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload

Does anyone know of a good alternative to uploadify.  I paid for their HTML version but this nor the flash version works in IE9. Shame as it's exactly what I'm after.

Are there any products out there that are similar?

Thanks

Comment: You just want a product suggestion? Not really what StackOverflow exists for to be honest.

Comment: It's a place where people in the know are looking all the time so thought I'd ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get uploadify/uploadifive to work in my project either

I ended up using [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/)

Comment: Thanks to all suggestions, this one looks the one though.

Answer (score -1):

Plupload would be a good alternative -  http://www.plupload.com/

FancyUpload is another good one - http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/